# responsive iframe in pure css

Tags: css, iframe, drupal-7

I'm attempting to create a class for embedded youtube videos that will display them at 100% width in the div, and will adjust the height according to the video's aspect ratio.

I have found the following suggestion [here](http://www.bymichaellancaster.com/blog/fluid-iframe-and-images-without-javascript-plugins/):

```
.fluidMedia {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* proportion value to aspect ratio 16:9 (9 / 16 = 0.5625 or 56.25%) */
    padding-top: 30px;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.fluidMedia iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; 
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

<div class="fluidMedia">
    <iframe src="" frameborder="0"> </iframe>
</div>
```

but this relies on every video having the same aspect ratio to work. I'd prefer to write one class that just works, regardless of the video embedded into it. Can this be done without javascript?

Comment: I believe this can't be done. However, the JS isn't too complicated. See http://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php

Answer (score 0):

The only CSS solution is the one you used, where you need to set the ratio in your CSS file – therefore there is no generic frontend solution without JavaScript.

You could have Drupal extract the ratio for you, of course – and write it into an inline CSS style property like

```
<div class="fluidMedia" style="padding-bottom: <?=$imgWidth/$imgHeight?>">
```

How to get the Video ratio would be a Drupal or PHP question.

For the JavaScript Solutionsee AndyM's link: http://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php